# How to include a counter in FlatFileItemWriter in Spring Batch when writing rows to a csv file

Tags: spring-batch

So, I'm using FlatFileItemWriter to write a csv file from data that I can successfully read from a database.

I'm struggling with how to write an integer number (i.e., row counter) corresponding to the row that I'm writing to the file. Seems like an easy thing to do, but quite simply I am stumped.

Everything is working (file is being produced from the data being read from a database). But I just can't seem to figure out how to implement my getCount() method in a way that gets me the corresponding row's count. I'm thinking it has something to do with leveraging the ChunkContext, but I can't seem to figure it out.

So I have the following in bean in my job configuration.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter() throws Exception {

    FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    itemWriter.setLineAggregator(new CustomerLineAggregator());
    itemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("/some/directory/file.csv"));
    itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

    return itemWriter;
}
```

I also have the following LineAggregator implementation.

```
public class CustomerLineAggregator implements LineAggregator<Customer> {
    
    private ChunkContext chunkContext;
    
    @BeforeChunk
    private void beforeChunk(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        this.setChunkContext(chunkContext);
    }
        
    @Override
    public String aggregate(Customer item) {
        
        return getCount() + "," + convertTime(item.getTime(), 3) + " ET," + item.getCustomerId() + "," + item.getLink() + "," + item.getName();
    }
    
    
    private String convertTime(String timeString, int offset) {
        
        LocalTime timeObject = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
        
        LocalTime timeOffsetObject = timeObject.plusHours(offset);
        
        return timeOffsetObject.toString();
        
    }
    
    private String getCount() {
        // how do I make use of the chunk context to infer the integer corresponding to the item assuming my chunk size is 1.
        return someCountString;
    }
    

    public ChunkContext getChunkContext() {
        return chunkContext;
    }

    public void setChunkContext(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        this.chunkContext = chunkContext;
    }
    

}
```

The expected output file should look like the following:

```
1, 10:09 ET, 742, https://www.firm.com, John Doe
2, 12:30 ET, 235, http://www.firm.com, Jane Doe
3, 9:21 ET, 398, http://www.thomas.io, Thomas Chan
4, 14:38 ET, 104, http://www.googl.com, Cindy Chen
```

I can successfully produce the above with the exception of the first column, which is simply the row count for each record. Anything I've tried fails to reset itself in between job runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ItemCountAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemCountAware.html) interface for that. This interface is to implement by your domain object (which seems to be `Customer` in your case) and will be called at reading time by any reader that extends `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`.

So if your reader is one them, you can get the item count on your items and use it as needed in your `LineAggregator`.

**EDIT: add option when the reader does not extend `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`**

You can always assign the item number in a `ItemReadListener#afterRead` and use that in your aggregator, something like:

```
class ItemNumberListener implements ItemReadListener<Customer> {
    int number;
    @Override
    public void afterRead(Customer customer) {
        customer.setNumber(number++);
    }
    // other methods from ItemReadListener
}
```

Once that in place, you register this listener in your step and use the item number in your `LineAggregator`. This method works with all readers (cursor-based or paging-based).

NB: If you can't add a field + getter/setter in the `Customer` object (probably a class you can't modify), you can wrap it in a custom object like `NumberAwareCustomer` and use that type in your batch application.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! I'm using a RepositoryItemReader<Customer> to query the data that I want to write to CSV. If I extend AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader in the associated reader class, how do I then access the count in my  LineAggregator<Customer> class that I'm using in FlatFileItemWriter? Do I inject something into my writer class or my LIneAggregator class? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to do that. You can use a listener to assign the item number which works will all readers. I edited the answer with an example.